# Difference Quotient and Function Transformation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm having some trouble with a set of problems, and It's summer work so I have no teacher to go to for help.

The header on the section reads "Use the difference quotient to find the transformations of the functions". This is the only text provided. The following problems are polynomials, square root functions, and 1/x functions. The issue is, I can't for the life of me figure out what the difference quotient is supposed to have to do with function transformations. What's more, I have no idea why I wouldn't just get the transformations by just looking at the functions like normally.

One example problem is $\sqrt{-2x+3}$ for context. I just have no idea what I'm supposed to do, and researching the problem hasn't given me anything useful.

Any help at all would be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You haven't provided enough information yet. If you edit the question to tell us what transformation of that function is called for perhaps we can help. The more context you provide the better.
Difference quotient" is an idea that is central to the calculation of derivatives. Have they already been introduced before  this section?

Comment: @EthanBolker I do know what the difference quotient is, and I have some basics of calculus (integrals, derivatives, etc) in the bag. I'd love to provide more context or which transformation is asked for, but the line I quoted is the ONLY text provided for the section.

Comment: In Wikipedia we can find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_quotient Are you dealing with derivatives?

Comment: @mfl I don't believe this is supposed to use derivatives, but it might. Thank you for the link, but I do know what the difference quotient is. My confusion comes from connecting this to the transformation of a function.

Comment: What it is not clear to me is what "transformation of a function" means. At least, whithout more context.